# MongoDB / PHP Library: $regex does not work

Tags: php, regex, mongodb

There are no errors & also no results.
My query looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [$or] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [title] => Array
                        (
                            [$regex] => /.*Palmer \- The ArT oF.*/
                            [$options] => i
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

If I change `title` to match the entire string from database, it works.
I tried the same query with MongoChef and it works.

Also tried to change the `title` value with:
1.  `new MongoDB\BSON\Regex('Palmer - The ArT oF', 'i');`
2. direct regex string `/.*Palmer \- The ArT oF.*/i`
...but still no results.

This is the Cursor object of the `find()` operation:

```
MongoDB\Driver\Cursor Object
(
    [cursor] => Array
        (
            [stamp] => 0
            [is_command] => 
            [sent] => 1
            [done] => 1
            [end_of_event] => 1
            [in_exhaust] => 
            [has_fields] => 
            [query] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [$query] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [$or] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [title] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [$regex] => /.*Palmer \- The ArT oF.*/
                                                    [$options] => i
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

            [fields] => stdClass Object
                (
                )

            [read_preference] => Array
                (
                    [mode] => 1
                    [tags] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [flags] => 0
            [skip] => 0
            [limit] => 0
            [count] => 1
            [batch_size] => 0
            [ns] => laravel.movie_list
        )

    [server_id] => 1
)
```

I'm  using the [mongo-php-library](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library) for this operations.

Answer (score 1):

We should use '^Hello' instead of /^Hello/'. So, the following will work:

```
$filter = ['NAME' => new MongoDB\BSON\Regex('^Hello', 'i')]; // Works
$cursor = $collection->find($filter);
```

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Also, when comparing two **distinct** regex objects the returned result is true.

```
$a = new Regex('a', 'i');
$b = new Regex('b', 'i');
var_dump($a == $b); // will return true
var_dump($a === $b); // will return false
```